# XML to JSON: How to reconstruct the order of nodes after conversion to JSON

Tags: json, xml, exist-db

I am currently working with eXist-db as an XML/TEI database and Angular for the website creation. The Angular code is requesting data from the eXist-db and I chose to make the eXist-db respond with JSON. I have been assuming that JSON is the most suitable data format for ths task.

I use the following XQuery code to create the JSON from a fixed XML file (I am currently just starting/testing all this) in the eXist-db:

```
xquery version "3.0";
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";
declare option output:method "json";
declare option output:media-type "application/json";
let $doc := doc("/db/data/Drucktexte/playground/Test_Angular_ngFor.xml")
return
   <result>{$doc}</result>
```

My problem: In XML there are e.g. <p> nodes that basically contain text. And there might be other sub-nodes embedded in this text content of the <p> node. In XML, the order of text and other nodes is serial and thus clear.

The following shows some XML with two <p> nodes. The only difference between those two <p> nodes is the order of their sub-nodes - e.g. the appearance of <pagebreak>:

```
<TEI>
<p n="1">The first text fragment
    <app>The first app fragment</app>
    The second text fragment
    <app>The second app fragment</app>
    The third text fragment
    <pagebreak/>
    The fourth text fragment
    <app>The third app fragment</app>
</p>
<p n="2">The first text fragment
    <app>The first app fragment</app>
    The second text fragment
    <pagebreak/>
    The third text fragment
    <app>The second app fragment</app>
    The fourth text fragment
    <app>The third app fragment</app>
</p>
```

When the XML is converted to JSON, I get isolated arrays of same node types. I currently do not see how I could restore the correct order of those array elements to display all those elements/nodes on the website in the correct order. After the upper XML is converted to JSON, both <p> nodes look exactly the same:

```
[
 {
  "@n": "1",
  "#text": [
     "The first text fragment",
     "The second text fragment",
     "The third text fragment",
     "The fourth text fragment"
  ],
  "app": [
     "The first app fragment",
     "The second app fragment",
     "The third app fragment"
  ],
  "pagebreak": []
},
{
  "@n": "2",
  "#text": [
     "The first text fragment",
     "The second text fragment",
     "The third text fragment",
     "The fourth text fragment"
  ],
  "app": [
     "The first app fragment",
     "The second app fragment",
     "The third app fragment"
  ],
  "pagebreak": []
}]
```

It is currently impossible for me to find out after which text fragment the pagebreak node would have to be inserted in each <p>. I did some research about this XML to JSON problem but could not find anything helpful. On the other hand, I cannot imagine that I am the first person facing such a problem.

I was thinking about adding some data to the JSON that represents the structure of all nodes and sub-nodes but I guess there must be a more elegant way.

So any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Could you say more about the XML-to-JSON conversion that's going on? Is the JSON form you show here required by your Angular application? XQuery 3.1 has built-in support for parsing and serializing JSON, so you can write XQuery that generates JSON that preserves the order of your nodes. For example, see http://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPgCcoF.

Comment: As you have noted, the method you are using to convert from XML to JSON does not preserve node order.

If order matters, then you need to change the design of the JSON data structure that is being generated from the XML.

Better yet — Don't convert to JSON in the first place. XML and JSON have different strengths and the data you have appears to be much better served by XML then it would be by JSON.

Comment: Thank you @joewiz for coming back to me. I added some more information, especially the XQuery code I use on the server. You can see I am using a very simple code that just takes the whole XML file and sends it out as JSON. I understand now that I might have to create a more specific XQuery routine like the one in the link you posted to parse and serialize my TEI data.

I hope I answer your 2nd question about the JSON form for the Angular application by saying that I chose JSON because it seems the most "comfortable" data format to work with in Angular/TypeScript. It is not required though.

Comment: Ah, thanks for adding this information. Your code uses a somewhat eXist-specific method of transforming arbitrary XML into JSON nodes, documented here: https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/wiki/blogs/eXist/JSONSerializer. (eXist isn't alone among XQuery implementations in having implemented something to help people generate JSON before the spec added full JSON support.) If that transformation rubric behavior doesn't provide the serialization you need, then you'll need to write your own; or, of course, you're welcome to adapt the one I posted.

Comment: Here's another version of the `jsonify` function that uses a somewhat more compact format, inspired by BaseX's equally implementation-specific JSON serialization format produced before the spec, [JsonML](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/JSON_Module#JsonML_Format), which has the benefits of being both compact and order-preserving: http://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtpA.

Comment: A slight fix/improvement on attribute handling: http://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtpA/2

Comment: Thank you a lot joewiz and @Quentin for commenting on this. I understand now that the problem is not between the Angular and the JSON, but the JSON should be processed in a different way so that it represents more of the original XML structures.

Or maybe switch back to responses in XML - I will check on the advantages of that.

Thanks also for the various code examples. I will definitely check on them and try a bit more what is the best solution.

P.S.: I tried to mark your user names in my comments. I follow the SO guidelines for that but still, those names are not highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code uses a somewhat eXist-specific method of transforming arbitrary XML into JSON nodes, documented here: https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/wiki/blogs/eXist/JSONSerializer. (eXist isn't alone among XQuery implementations in having developed a facility for generating JSON before the XQuery Working Group added full JSON support in XQuery 3.1.) While that transformation does a good job, it may not be exactly what you need for your use case.

Luckily, eXist does support [XQuery 3.1's standard, built-in capabilities for parsing and serializing JSON](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#json). This means you can write XQuery that generates JSON that preserves the order of your nodes, and performs any other custom behavior in the process.

For two examples of XML-to-JSON transformations that preserve node order, see:

1. A completely custom, albeit verbose transformation of your XML into JSON: https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPgCcoF
2. A more compact transformation of your XML into JsonML: https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtpA.